# Изменить .cs на .cshtml

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp

После обновления vs все вьюшки изменились с .cshtml в g.cshtml.cs

[Вот что сейчас](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8SRTi.png)

[И вот](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JCm36.png)

Как вернуть обратно в cshtml ?

Comment: почему вас вообще волнует автосгенерированный код?

Comment: А как мне его редактировать? Он заменил обычный cshtml файл и тепер проект не собирается.

Comment: он не может заменить обычный файл, так как у него g в пути файла стоит - то есть он был сгенерирован автоматом. Зачем вам редактировать автосгенерированные файлы?

Comment: Говорю же, после обновления vs в проекте все файлы .cshtml (больше 50) заменились на это. И обычных файлов нигде нет.

Comment: это у вас было и в прошлом проекте (эти файлы генерируются в папке obj, если я не ошибаюсь), а куда пропали ваши файлы с разметкой я не имею понятия.

Answer (score 0):

Запиши это в файл, назови kakugodno.py кинь в папку с этими файлами и запусти.
Нужен третий питон. (https://www.python.org/)

```
import shutil 
import os

files = os.listdir()

for key in range(0, len(files)):

    if 'g.cshtml.cs' in str(files[key]):
        newname = str(files[key]).replace('g.cshtml.cs','.cshtml')
        shutil.move(files[key],newname)
```

Comment: боюсь что автора интересовало то, как решить его проблему с учетом его собственного стека технологий и возможно еще услышать объяснение того что у него произошло и как ему дальше с этим жить. В любом случае спасибо за ответ.